# Webcomponent support for Tabulator Table

Tags: javascript, web-component, tabulator, native-web-component

I would like to use the very nice Tabulator (http://tabulator.info/) javascript table in a webcomponent.

However it looks like the main Tabulator instance can only be created via a html selector like this:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {...});
```

Unfortunately looks like the `#example-table` is not visible in the shadowDom of webcomponents:

```
class WcProjects extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        // Attach a shadow root to the element.
        let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<div id="example-table"></div>`;
}
connectedCallback() {
    var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {...});
}
```

Is there another way of instantiating the Tabulator table?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Show what have you tried yourself, problems you have encountered. Help community to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tabulator constructor accepts either a selector or a DOM node into the constructor element of the table, ie:

```
var tableHolder = document.createElement("div");
var table = new Tabulator(tableHolder , {...});
```

so as long as you have access to that node, which your component should give you, you can pass that into the constructor

Comment: Works perfectly. I tried this but had a small mistake in the code and the feature was documented. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It works partially. Tabulator uses in some places document.body.appendChild(). So the new created element is not visible to shadow dom. E.g. the select editor doesn't work