# Shadow Dom support for tabulator-table

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I try to use the Tabulator (http://tabulator.info/) javascript table in a webcomponent.
I've managed to initiate the table as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54451195/webcomponent-support-for-tabulator-table) question:

The problem is the usage of `document.body.appendChild()` e.g. in select editor. The result is, that select box doesn't appear, because it is not visible to the table, which is inside a shadow dom.

Answer (score 0):

This will be happening because the table is not yet visible. Tabulator needs to be visible when its internal virtual DOM is updated in order to calculate the dimensions of its contents correctly.

You can call the ***redraw*** function on the table when it is made visible again and it will fix the issue:

```js
table.redraw();
```